# How can I change Untrusted App Developer message?

Tags: ios, deployment, enterprise

I am responsible for maintaining an ios application that was written by another company. When I deploy the application to a device I get the following message:

Untrusted App Developer
Do you trust the developer "iPhone Distribution: XYZ Consulting, LLC" TO RUN APPS ON YOUR IPHONE?

What do I need to do to replace "iPhone Distribution: XYZ Consulting, LLC" with "iPhone Distribution: My Company, LLC"?

I searched the source code and was not able to find this string.

I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: When you deploy how? You installed the .ipa via iTunes? End users aren't going to see this anyway, so what's the real issue?

Comment: I am sorry I was not clear. This is an enterprise application and is not installed via iTunes. I know that as of ios 8 I cannot get rid of this message - I just need to change the company name.

Comment: That message isn't coming from your app its coming from iOS. Have you created an iOS developer account and created development and distribution provisioning profiles? Probably not from the sound of it. First thing you need to do is read an iOS app development 101 book or beginning tutorial and learn about developer accounts and signing and provisioning. It will be one of the first topics covered in a app development beginner book. You need to sign your app with your own companies profiles not the other companies.

Answer (score 0):

Log into your apple developer account's member center. If you don't already have a production App Store and Ad Hoc certificate, request one.

Create an App ID for that app if you haven't already. Create a new Distribution provisioning profile for that app.

In XCode (you have the source code, of course), create an archive and export it for Enterprise Deployment. XCode will prompt you for the certificate and provisioning profile to use. You might need to click "View Accounts..." and click the refresh button if your certificate and provisioning profile aren't showing.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have an enterprise certificate that belongs to your own Developer Profile that you registered as "My Company, LLC", it cannot be changed.

The enterprise certificate takes its name from the company that registered the Developer Profile.